# Can't get emacs + ritz-nrepl working on a Macintosh system

Tags: emacs, clojure, installation, pallet

I'm having trouble getting ritz-nrepl to work. Here's what I've done:

1. Started with a clean system (on Mac OS X, Mountain Lion)--no emacs.app, no ~/.emacs.d directory
2. Followed the instructions on https://github.com/pallet/ritz/tree/develop/nrepl (I put the init.el file in ~/.emacs.d)
3. Opened my core.clj file, then run `M-x nrepl-ritz-jack-in`
4. The result was a set of error messages:

   ```
   at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5237)
   at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
   at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
   at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5271)
   at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
   at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
   at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5352)
   at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:436)
   at ritz.nrepl.project$eval3125$loading_\_4505_\_auto_\__\_3126.invoke(project.clj:1)
   at ritz.nrepl.project$eval3125.invoke(project.clj:1)
   at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6465)
   at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6455)
   at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:6902)
   at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:357)
   at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:348)
   at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:427)
   at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:398)
   at clojure.core$load$fn__4610.invoke(core.clj:5386)
   at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5385)
   at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
   at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5200)
   at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5237)
   at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
   at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
   at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5271)
   at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
   at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:604)
   at clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:5363)
   at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:930)
   at ritz.nrepl.debug_eval$eval2877$loading__4505__auto____2878.invoke(debug_eval.clj:1)
   at ritz.nrepl.debug_eval$eval2877.invoke(debug_eval.clj:1)
   at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6465)
   at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6455)
   at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:6902)
   at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:357)
   at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:348)
   at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:427)
   at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:398)
   at clojure.core$load$fn__4610.invoke(core.clj:5386)
   at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5385)
   at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
   at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5200)
   at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5237)
   at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
   at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
   at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5271)
   at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
   at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:604)
   at clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:5363)
   at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:3659)
   at ritz.nrepl$eval5$loading_\_4505_\_auto_\_\_\_6.invoke(nrepl.clj:1)
   at ritz.nrepl$eval5.invoke(nrepl.clj:1)
   at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6465)
   at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6455)
   at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:6902)
   at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:357)
   at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:348)
   at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:427)
   at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:398)
   at clojure.core$load$fn__4610.invoke(core.clj:5386)
   at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5385)
   at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
   at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5200)
   at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5237)
   at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
   at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
   at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5271)
   at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
   at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
   at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5352)
   at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
   at user$eval1.invoke(NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
   at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6465)
   at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6455)
   at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6454)
   at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6431)
   at clojure.core$eval.invoke(core.clj:2795)
   at clojure.main$eval_opt.invoke(main.clj:296)
   at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:315)
   at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:348)
   at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:426)
   at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
   at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:405)
   at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:163)
   at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:518)
   at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
   ```

   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: ex-info in this context
       at clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException(Util.java:156)
       at clojure.lang.Compiler.resolveIn(Compiler.java:6720)
       at clojure.lang.Compiler.resolve(Compiler.java:6664)
       at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSymbol(Compiler.java:6625)
       at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6198)
       ... 171 more

### The debugging

I checked to see that the proper libraries had loaded:

```
package-activated-list is a variable defined in `package.el'.
Its value is (nrepl-ritz nrepl clojure-mode)
```

Searching the Internet, I found the following at https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/clojure/KbVSpHG9Y8s

In this thread, Hugo Duncan replies to "Tim":

```
This [the error "Unable to resolve symbol: ex-info"] seems to be an issue 
with clojure 1.4 not being used in the
controlling vm, and should have been fixed by
https://github.com/pallet/ritz/issues/53, which will be included in the
next release.
```

The webpage https://github.com/pallet/ritz/issues/53 is an issue titled "tools.jar missing from classpath with lein ritz-nrepl," for which the fix is:

```
"Ensure tools.jar is on the classpath with lein ritz-nrepl"
```

On Mac OS X, this is tricky, but I finally verified from within Emacs that $PATH is:

```
"/bin/bash /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_15.jdk/Contents/Home:
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:"
```

When I run `M-x nrepl-ritz-jack-in` in Emacs, I get the same error as above. (I also verify that, on my Mac, /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_15.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/tools.jar in fact exists.)

Now, that space character in the output from $PATH worries me. I reread the "Ensure tools.jar..." message again and see that it's telling me that if `lein ritz-nrepl` runs correctly, that means that "tools.jar is on the classpath." Here's my output:

```
Greggs-Mac-Pro:src gr$ cd /Users/gr/tech/cljprojects/combolock/src/combolock
Greggs-Mac-Pro:combolock gr$ ls
core.clj    core.clj~
Greggs-Mac-Pro:combolock gr$ $PATH
-bash: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_15.jdk/Contents/Home:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin: No such file or directory
Greggs-Mac-Pro:combolock gr$ lein ritz-nrepl
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: ex-info in this context, compiling:(leiningen/core/classpath.clj:128)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6235)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6177)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3452)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6411)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6216)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6177)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$ThrowExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:2239)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6409)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6216)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6177)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:5572)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$TryExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:2117)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6409)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6216)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6177)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:5572)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$LetExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:5873)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6409)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6216)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6397)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6216)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6177)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:5572)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$FnMethod.parse(Compiler.java:5008)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$FnExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3629)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6407)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6216)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6397)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6216)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.access$100(Compiler.java:37)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$DefExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:492)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6409)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6216)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6177)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6469)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:6902)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:357)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:348)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:427)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:398)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__4610.invoke(core.clj:5386)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5385)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5200)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5237)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5271)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5352)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:703)
    at leiningen.core.project$eval3195$loading__4505__auto____3196.invoke(project.clj:1)
    at leiningen.core.project$eval3195.invoke(project.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6465)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6455)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:6902)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:357)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:348)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:427)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:398)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__4610.invoke(core.clj:5386)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5385)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5200)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5237)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5271)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5352)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:551)
    at leiningen.core.main$eval3131$loading__4505__auto____3132.invoke(main.clj:1)
    at leiningen.core.main$eval3131.invoke(main.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6465)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6455)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:6902)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:357)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:348)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:427)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:398)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__4610.invoke(core.clj:5386)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5385)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5200)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5237)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5271)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5352)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:436)
    at ritz.nrepl.project$eval3125$loading__4505__auto____3126.invoke(project.clj:1)
    at ritz.nrepl.project$eval3125.invoke(project.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6465)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6455)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:6902)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:357)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:348)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:427)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:398)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__4610.invoke(core.clj:5386)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5385)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5200)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5237)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5271)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:604)
    at clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:5363)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:930)
    at ritz.nrepl.debug_eval$eval2877$loading__4505__auto____2878.invoke(debug_eval.clj:1)
    at ritz.nrepl.debug_eval$eval2877.invoke(debug_eval.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6465)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6455)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:6902)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:357)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:348)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:427)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:398)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__4610.invoke(core.clj:5386)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5385)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5200)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5237)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5271)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:604)
    at clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:5363)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:3659)
    at ritz.nrepl$eval5$loading__4505__auto____6.invoke(nrepl.clj:1)
    at ritz.nrepl$eval5.invoke(nrepl.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6465)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6455)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:6902)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:357)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:348)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:427)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:398)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__4610.invoke(core.clj:5386)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5385)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5200)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5237)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5271)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5352)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at user$eval1.invoke(NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6465)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6455)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6454)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6431)
    at clojure.core$eval.invoke(core.clj:2795)
    at clojure.main$eval_opt.invoke(main.clj:296)
    at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:315)
    at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:348)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:426)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:405)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:163)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:518)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: ex-info in this context
    at clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException(Util.java:156)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.resolveIn(Compiler.java:6720)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.resolve(Compiler.java:6664)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSymbol(Compiler.java:6625)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6198)
    ... 171 more
Subprocess failed
Greggs-Mac-Pro:combolock gr$
```

If you look at the very bottom and the very top, you will find that:

1. I still get the same "Unable to resolve symbol: ex-info" error message
2. The current directory is the `src` directory of my `combolock` Leiningen 2 project (yes, lein2, not lein1)
3. Path contains `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_15.jdk/Contents/Home`, which, as far as I can tell, is the same as $JAVA_HOME would be on a Windows machine

### The plea

So, as far as I can tell, `tools.jar` *is* available, but I'm still getting this "Unable to resolve symbol: ex-info" error.

It's late, I'm tired, and I hope somebody will see something that I don't. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fact: `lein ritz-nrepl` had returned an error. In a moment of fuzzy-thinking intuition, it occurred to me that this might mean that the underlying problem had to do with *Java*, not Emacs. I investigated this on the StackExchange "Ask Different" (Apple-oriented) website and read about how a Mac OS X system "finds" Java (especially since both Java 6--from Apple--as well as Java 7--from Oracle--are installed on my system). It's confusing.

In the end, Apple's way of doing things *was* working perfectly. I had fouled things up by manually changing the value of `PATH` in the `.bash_profile` customization file. Once I removed the lines that modified `PATH`, `lein ritz-nrepl` worked and, in Emacs, `M-x nrepl-ritz-jack-in` worked first time! Yikes!

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the latest version of nrepl-ritz.el? Your case seems to be the same as the issue discussed at https://github.com/pallet/ritz/issues/53.

Comment: Yes, I checked, and I have the latest version. Thanks.