# ritz-nrepl with lein not working on osx

Tags: macos, emacs, clojure, leiningen, nrepl

I would like to use ritz-nrepl for debugging purposes from within Emacs. Because it already fails with `lein ritz-nrepl` I did not go further with the Emacs integration yet.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jdi.connect.VMStartException: 
   VM initialization failed for: ...
```

The full stacktrace is shown at the end of the post. I know that this exception was around for some time and that there are potential fixes but that did not help in my case:

- [A Working nrepl-ritz Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15094604/cant-get-emacs-ritz-nrepl-working-on-a-macintosh-system)
- [Can't get emacs + ritz-nrepl working on a Macintosh system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15094604/cant-get-emacs-ritz-nrepl-working-on-a-macintosh-system).

Otherwise, nrepl et al. are working perfectly fine on my system. I'm using `clojure 1.5.1` with

```
$> lein version
Leiningen 2.2.0 on Java 1.7.0_25 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
```

My `~/.lein/profiles.clj` looks like this:

```
{:user
  {:plugins [[lein-ritz "0.7.0"]]
   :dependencies [[nrepl-inspect "0.3.0"]
             [org.clojure/tools.trace "0.7.5"]
             [ritz/ritz-nrepl-middleware "0.7.0"]
             [ritz/ritz-debugger "0.7.0"]
             [clojure-complete "0.2.3"]]
   :repl-options {:nrepl-middleware
             [ritz.nrepl.middleware.javadoc/wrap-javadoc
              ritz.nrepl.middleware.simple-complete/wrap-simple-complete
              inspector.middleware/wrap-inspect]}}}
```

From within a lein project I run `lein ritz-nrepl`. But this fails with the above exception. I've run `lein ritz-nrepl -l trace` but found no useful output. What can I do to get this running?

BTW. I've tested this with the the `ritz 0.7.1-SNAPSHOT` but the errors persist.

Am I missing something obvious? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Full stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jdi.connect.VMStartException: VM initialization failed for: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java -XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=London:58846,suspend=y -cp /private/tmp/test/test:/private/tmp/test/src:/private/tmp/test/dev-resources:/private/tmp/test/resources:/private/tmp/test/target/classes:/Users/me/.m2/repository/reply/reply/0.1.9/reply-0.1.9.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/thnetos/cd-client/0.3.6/cd-client-0.3.6.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/aether/aether-connector-wagon/1.13.1/aether-connector-wagon-1.13.1.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/quoin/quoin/0.1.0/quoin-0.1.0.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/useful/useful/0.8.3-alpha8/useful-0.8.3-alpha8.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/clojure/java.classpath/0.2.0/java.classpath-0.2.0.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/clj-stacktrace/clj-stacktrace/0.2.4/clj-stacktrace-0.2.4.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/clojure/core.cache/0.6.2/core.cache-0.6.2.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/indexer/indexer-core/4.1.3/indexer-core-4.1.3.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/tcrawley/dynapath/0.2.3/dynapath-0.2.3.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/classlojure/classlojure/0.6.6/classlojure-0.6.6.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/ritz/ritz-nrepl-core/0.7.1-SNAPSHOT/ritz-nrepl-core-0.7.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/clojure/tools.trace/0.7.5/tools.trace-0.7.5.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/clojure/data.xml/0.0.3/data.xml-0.0.3.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-http/2.2/wagon-http-2.2.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/aether/aether-connector-file/1.13.1/aether-connector-file-1.13.1.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/stencil/stencil/0.3.1/stencil-0.3.1.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.14/plexus-interpolation-1.14.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-bean/2.2.3/sisu-inject-bean-2.2.3.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/indexer/indexer-artifact/4.1.3/indexer-artifact-4.1.3.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/lucene/lucene-memory/3.6.1/lucene-memory-3.6.1.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/jakarta-regexp/jakarta-regexp/1.4/jakarta-regexp-1.4.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/2.0.7/plexus-utils-2.0.7.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.2.2/httpclient-4.2.2.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/slingshot/slingshot/0.8.0/slingshot-0.8.0.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/jackson-dataformat-smile/2.0.6/jackson-dataformat-smile-2.0.6.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.2.2/httpcore-4.2.2.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/clojars/trptcolin/sjacket/0.1.0.2/sjacket-0.1.0.2.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.0.6/jackson-core-2.0.6.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-http-shared4/2.2/wagon-http-shared4-2.2.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-model-builder/3.0.4/maven-model-builder-3.0.4.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/clojure/tools.macro/0.1.1/tools.macro-0.1.1.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/cheshire/cheshire/4.0.3/cheshire-4.0.3.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/cemerick/pomegranate/0.0.13/pomegranate-0.0.13.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/jline/jline/2.8/jline-2.8.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/scout/scout/0.1.0/scout-0.1.0.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/clj-http/clj-http/0.5.8/clj-http-0.5.8.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/leiningen-core/leiningen-core/2.0.0/leiningen-core-2.0.0.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-aether-provider/3.0.4/maven-aether-provider-3.0.4.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/aether/aether-util/1.13.1/aether-util-1.13.1.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/clj-http-lite/clj-http-lite/0.2.0/clj-http-lite-0.2.0.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/nrepl-inspect/nrepl-inspect/0.3.0/nrepl-inspect-0.3.0.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/ritz/ritz-debugger/0.7.1-SNAPSHOT/ritz-debugger-0.7.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/jsoup/jsoup/1.6.1/jsoup-1.6.1.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/aether/aether-api/1.13.1/aether-api-1.13.1.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojure/1.5.1/clojure-1.5.1.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/net/cgrand/regex/1.1.0/regex-1.1.0.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-classworlds/2.4/plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/3.0.3/sisu-guice-3.0.3-no_aop.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.6/commons-codec-1.6.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/trptcolin/versioneer/0.1.0/versioneer-0.1.0.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/lucene/lucene-highlighter/3.6.1/lucene-highlighter-3.6.1.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/aether/aether-impl/1.13.1/aether-impl-1.13.1.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/bultitude/bultitude/0.1.7/bultitude-0.1.7.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/robert/hooke/1.3.0/hooke-1.3.0.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/ritz/ritz-nrepl/0.7.1-SNAPSHOT/ritz-nrepl-0.7.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/ritz/ritz-repl-utils/0.7.1-SNAPSHOT/ritz-repl-utils-0.7.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-repository-metadata/3.0.4/maven-repository-metadata-3.0.4.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/clojure/tools.nrepl/0.2.3/tools.nrepl-0.2.3.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/lucene/lucene-queries/3.6.1/lucene-queries-3.6.1.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/cemerick/drawbridge/0.0.6/drawbridge-0.0.6.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-model/3.0.4/maven-model-3.0.4.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/clojure/tools.namespace/0.2.3/tools.namespace-0.2.3.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/clojure/tools.cli/0.2.1/tools.cli-0.2.1.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/aether/aether-spi/1.13.1/aether-spi-1.13.1.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.2.2/httpmime-4.2.2.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/lucene/lucene-core/3.6.1/lucene-core-3.6.1.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/leiningen/leiningen/2.0.0/leiningen-2.0.0.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/ritz/ritz-nrepl-middleware/0.7.1-SNAPSHOT/ritz-nrepl-middleware-0.7.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/clojure-complete/clojure-complete/0.2.3/clojure-complete-0.2.3.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-plexus/2.2.3/sisu-inject-plexus-2.2.3.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-provider-api/2.2/wagon-provider-api-2.2.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/net/cgrand/parsley/0.9.1/parsley-0.9.1.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/clojure/java.classpath/0.2.0/java.classpath-0.2.0-sources.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.14/plexus-interpolation-1.14-sources.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5-sources.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1-sources.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojure/1.5.1/clojure-1.5.1-sources.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-classworlds/2.4/plexus-classworlds-2.4-sources.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.6/commons-codec-1.6-sources.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/clojure/tools.nrepl/0.2.3/tools.nrepl-0.2.3-sources.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/clojure/tools.namespace/0.2.3/tools.namespace-0.2.3-sources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar clojure.main -i /private/var/folders/07/mlnfr3g573g13w374qm17s_c0000gn/T/ritz-init3860568408072505479.clj
at com.sun.tools.jdi.AbstractLauncher$Helper.launchAndAccept(AbstractLauncher.java:192)
at com.sun.tools.jdi.AbstractLauncher.launch(AbstractLauncher.java:132)
at com.sun.tools.jdi.SunCommandLineLauncher.launch(SunCommandLineLauncher.java:235)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:93)
at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod(Reflector.java:28)
at ritz.jpda.jdi$launch.invoke(jdi.clj:86)
at ritz.jpda.jdi_vm$launch_vm.invoke(jdi_vm.clj:176)
at ritz.jpda.debug$launch_vm.invoke(debug.clj:59)
at ritz.nrepl$start_jpda_server.invoke(nrepl.clj:259)
at user$eval6209.invoke(NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6511)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6500)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6501)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6477)
at clojure.core$eval.invoke(core.clj:2797)
at clojure.main$eval_opt.invoke(main.clj:297)
at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:316)
at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:349)
at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:427)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:419)
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:163)
at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:532)
at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is ancient, but I have a possible answer, that is still relevant in 2019 because I had a similar issue. The problem is that your debugger is trying to connect via JDI to the process to be debugged but it fails. Let's look at the long command line after the "VM initialization failed" message:

```
 /.../.../java ... -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=London:58846,suspend=y ... clojure.main ...
```

This is the command line that JDI uses to launch the JVM that, in turns, runs clojure + your program to be debugged. The `-Xrunjdwp` options means that, after being launched, the JVM will try to connect to a debugger through a socket. The `address=London:58846` string is, precisely, the network address and port where the debugger process is listening, waiting for an inferior to connect. The problem with some versions of macOS (reported with Sierra and, in my case, Mojave) is that macOS is unable to resolve the hostname (`London` in your case) to an IP address, preventing the JVM to connect to the debugger. In my case this happens because the hostname JDI is picking is my laptop's [local network name](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/find-your-computers-name-and-network-address-mchlp1177/mac). But I don't think it is your case, because the hostname in the above command line is `London`, and according to Apple "The local network name is your computer’s name with *.local* added": Since the hostname in your command line is not `London.local`, apparently in your case JDI is trying to use another, nonlocal network name for your computer.

Now for the solution, supposing that your `London` machine where you run the program to be debugged is the same where you run the debugger (that's quite the common case). What you need to do is to "convince" macOS to register the hostname and associate to it the IP address of your computer. Just for the record, in my case the workaround proposed at [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1131187/mac-local-domain-name-stopped-resolving/1131188#1131188?newreg=b3b2e27b0a25469ab05f5066ae0495c2) was sufficient: I started one of the sharing services, and macOS registered the local network name of my computer. In your case, not knowing much of your network settings, I am able to suggest only a ugly hack: Edit the `/etc/hosts` file (you must `sudo vim` or `sudo nano`) and map the loopback IP address `127.0.0.1` to your hostname by modifying the row

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
```

to

```
127.0.0.1    localhost    London
```

I know that having to modify `/etc/hosts` in 2019 is less than ideal...